# Input fields showing nil in Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a cookbook scaffold, allowing users to create many cookbooks. I associated the user_id to the cookbook in the controller, but the title and description is showing up nil in the rails database.

```
    class CookBooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cook_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /cook_books
  # GET /cook_books.json
  def index
    @cook_books = CookBook.all
  end

  # GET /cook_books/1
  # GET /cook_books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cook_books/new
  def new
    @cook_book = CookBook.new()
  end

  # GET /cook_books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cook_books
  # POST /cook_books.json
  def create
    @cook_book = CookBook.new(cook_book_params)
    @cook_book.user_id = current_user.id  


    respond_to do |format|
      if @cook_book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cook_book, notice: 'Cook book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cook_book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cook_book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cook_books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cook_books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cook_book.update(cook_book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cook_book, notice: 'Cook book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cook_book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cook_book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cook_books/1
  # DELETE /cook_books/1.json
  def destroy
    @cook_book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cook_books_url, notice: 'Cook book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cook_book
      @cook_book = CookBook.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cook_book_params
      params.require(:cook_book).permit(:title, :user_id, :description)
    end
end




class CookBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users 
end




ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140811235307) do

  create_table "cook_books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pages", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "header"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Any help appreciate it! thank you

EDIT! Form added

```
<%= form_for(@cook_book) do |f| %>
  <% if @cook_book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cook_book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cook_book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @cook_book.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT! Server Log

```
Started GET "/cook_books/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 02:21:05 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by CookBooksController#new as HTML
  Rendered cook_books/_form.html.erb (30.2ms)
  Rendered cook_books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (36.9ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (28.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 335ms (Views: 306.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)



Started POST "/cook_books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 02:21:15 -0400
Processing by CookBooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TNDketl0ixC8Lh/aAWIGf7SWeiwHZR9ITlEEpa7/+xM=", "cook_book"=>{"title"=>"Test title", "description"=>"test description "}, "commit"=>"Create Cookbook"}
**WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for CookBook: title, description
    app/controllers/cook_books_controller.rb:28:in `create'** (Just saw this)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "cook_books" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-12 06:21:15.547634"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-12 06:21:15.547634"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cook_books/8
Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)


Started GET "/cook_books/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 02:21:15 -0400
Processing by CookBooksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  CookBook Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "cook_books".* FROM "cook_books"  WHERE "cook_books"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  Rendered cook_books/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 30.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms
```

)

EDIT! Model

```
class CookBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users 
end
```

Comment: What is your rails version?

Comment: As it is, I don't see any issue. I'm assuming you're also using something like Devise for User authentication?

Comment: @EasyCo yeah I am using devise.

Comment: When you create a new book, are you getting the *Cook book was successfully created* confirmation?

Comment: Also try from terminal: `rails c` to get into Rails console. Then create an entry: `c = CookBook.create(user_id: 1, title: "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", description: "Always know where your towel is")`. Does `c` have all your saved attributes?

Comment: @EasyCo I am, just no title or description gets saved. Ultimately, I want recipes within the Cookbook, but I need the columns in the cookbook to save. I'm about to try your answer in terminal ..will update with response!

Comment: @EasyCo It didn't save the attributes in rails console. It gave all nil.

Comment: Can you post the `server log` generated when you `submit` your `form`?

Comment: Can you post your full `model` code?

Comment: I just saw this in the server log : **WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for CookBook: title, description
    app/controllers/cook_books_controller.rb:28:in `create'**

Comment: Hmm,ok.Can you post your list gems you have? I guess you have the gem `protected_attributes` which would be causing the problem here.

Comment: Try removing that gem.It is the problem when using strong parameters.

Comment: I removed it and it gave me this error when I started the server 

/Users/WhiteMacbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `attr_accessible' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: If your `User` model contains `attr_accessible`,then remove it too and try again.

Comment: Is there something is should replace attr_accessible with?

Comment: When using strong parameters,you don't require `attr_accessible`.

Comment: You should change `belongs_to :users` to `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: @JaugarChang Nice catch.Yes that could be also one of the problem.

Comment: the :users to :user didn't work sadly. If I remove attr, I assume I need to def a param for the :email, :password, etc..

Comment: Can you post your User model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is fine,but when looked at the `server log`,you have this warning

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes for CookBook: title,
>   description

And from the comments,it is confirmed that you have this gem `protected_attributes`.This adds the default `attr_accessible`.But when it comes with `Rails4`,this gem is not required.You need to remove it to get the things work.

**A small note:**

As **@Jaugar Chang** pointed,you have `belongs_to :users`.It should be `belongs_to :user`.It would lead to further problems.